# consolidate rows with same value using R

Tags: r

I have a CSV file where there are 4 columns. I would like to get answer by adding the 4th column values where the 3rd column values are same.

[The data that i have looks like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBEi1.png)

[Now i want to aggregate the above data like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26n1j.png)

Anyone can help me with your ideas!

Comment: please do not insert images, copy paste your code, and other stuff

Answer (score 0):

Using aggregate would do the trick here. Below I'm summing the `value` variable using `id` as the group (notice ids 6 and 10 are repeating).

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,6,7,8,9,10,10),
                 value = c(9,5,6,8,4,3,2,5,3,5,1,2))

df_sum <- aggregate(value ~ id, data=df, FUN=sum)
```